# htaccess combine folder with alias

Tags: .htaccess

I have 3 folders in a sub directory of my root directory i would like to combine.

My site map:

```
mywebsite.com
mywebsite.com/test/
mywebsite.com/test/one/
mywebsite.com/test/one/one.php
mywebsite.com/test/two/two.php
mywebsite.com/test/three/three.php
```

I would like to access:

```
mywebsite.com/test/one/one.php
mywebsite.com/test/two/two.php
mywebsite.com/test/three/three.php
```

by using:

```
mywebsite.com/test/combine/one.php
mywebsite.com/test/combine/two.php
mywebsite.com/test/combine/three.php
```

---

### Solution...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* - [E=directory:/test/]
RewriteRule .* - [E=one:one/]
RewriteRule .* - [E=two:two/]
RewriteRule .* - [E=three:three/]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:directory}%{ENV:one}$1 -f     [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:directory}%{ENV:one}$1 -d
RewriteRule ^combine/(.*)$  %{ENV:directory}%{ENV:one}$1    [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:directory}%{ENV:two}$1 -f     [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:directory}%{ENV:two}$1 -d
RewriteRule ^combine/(.*)$  %{ENV:directory}%{ENV:two}$1    [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:directory}%{ENV:three}$1 -f   [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:directory}%{ENV:three}$1 -d
RewriteRule ^combine/(.*)$  %{ENV:directory}%{ENV:three}$1  [L]
```

> This works but i would like to minimize the script

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way for consolidation, if you simplify it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test/$1/$1.php -f 
RewriteRule ^combine/(.*)(?:\.php)$  /test/$1/$1.php  [L]
```

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't work, i think the issue is with the cond %1

Comment: Yes sorry, wasn't thinking you can't use regex in the `teststring`.  However can't you just simplify it? You seem to only be looking for php files so try my update.

Comment: I don't have an .htaccess file. You mean the code? It tested fine for me. BTW are you including the `test` in the URL?

Comment: No  i am not including test, i get server misconfiguration error when using your code.

Comment: Oops there was a typo. in the first part of the rule. I fixed it.